# ngModel on a img

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to make something easy but, it doesn't work. I have this html

```
<div  class="positionDiv">
     <img class="eyes" ng-model="showPasswordIsChecked" ng-click="afficherMdp()"  ng-controller="creationCompteController"  src="images/eye.png" />
</div>
{{ showPasswordIsChecked }}
```

and this javascript

```
angular.module('starter').controller('creationCompteController',[
    '$scope',   
     function ($scope)
    {


        $scope.showPasswordIsChecked = false;


        //Affichage du template html
        $scope.afficherMdp = function()
        {
            if($scope.showPasswordIsChecked==true)
            {
                $scope.showPasswordIsChecked=false;
                alert($scope.showPasswordIsChecked);
            }else{
                $scope.showPasswordIsChecked=true;
                alert($scope.showPasswordIsChecked);
            }

        }

    }]);
```

I want, when i click on my image to change the value of showPassword to true or false. In the js file, the enter in the function, but in the html `{{ showPasswordIsChecked }}` shows nothing, as if the variable doesn't exist. How could I do please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind an `<img />` to a variable with `ng-model` :https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

You must use it on an input (or an element with an input behavior).

But you can do like this :

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('creationCompteController', function($scope) {
  $scope.showPasswordIsChecked = false;
});
```

```css
#my-checkbox {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="creationCompteController">
      <label for="my-checkbox">
          <input id="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" ng-model="showPasswordIsChecked" />
          <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/mono-general-4/128/eye-icon.png" />
      </label>
    
       {{ showPasswordIsChecked }}
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo http://dojo.telerik.com/OjaPa
You are printing model out of controller scope so that it is happening
Please check whether it is helpful or not

```
 <div ng-controller='creationCompteController'>
  <div  class="positionDiv">
   <img class="eyes" ng-model='showPasswordIsChecked'  ng-click="afficherMdp()"   src="images/eye.png" />
 </div>
 {{ showPasswordIsChecked }}
</div>
```

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think Your code works

Here is the Link [**Output**](https://output.jsbin.com/hunajopiso)

```
$scope.afficherMdp = function()
    {
        if($scope.showPasswordIsChecked==true)
        {
            $scope.showPasswordIsChecked=false;
            alert($scope.showPasswordIsChecked);
        }else{
            $scope.showPasswordIsChecked=true;
            alert($scope.showPasswordIsChecked);
        }
    }
```